# How do I stop this JS 'show and hide' button from revealing the content at first?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

Basically, I have 3 images and once the button is clicked it displays those images, however, when the page is loading up, the button is already toggled on and displays the images, once you click on it the images go. So the button works, but it starts off with displaying the contents which is not what I want.

```js
var a;
function show_hide()
{
    if(a==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("image").style.display="inline";
        return a=0;
    }

    else
    {
        document.getElementById("image").style.display="none";
        return a=1;
    }

}
```

```html
    <div id="image">
            <img class= "tree1" src="img/tree1.jpeg">
            <img class= "tree2" src="img/tree2.jpeg">
            <img class= "tree3" src="img/roots.jpeg">
        </div>
      <div>
        <button onclick="show_hide()">Click to Reveal</button>
      </div>

      <script src="showhideelement.js"></script>
```

Comment: All you need is basic css to hide by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class to define the style which you can toggle on clicking the button using [`DOMTokenList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).

Also, I will suggest you to avoid inline event handler.

**Demo:**

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', show_hide);
function show_hide()
{
  document.getElementById("image").classList.toggle('showHide');
}
```

```css
.showHide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="image" class="showHide">
      <img class= "tree1" src="img/tree1.jpeg">
      <img class= "tree2" src="img/tree2.jpeg">
      <img class= "tree3" src="img/roots.jpeg">
  </div>
<div>
  <button>Click to Reveal</button>
</div>

<script src="showhideelement.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a = 1 and make your div to display none.

HTML:

```
<div id="image" style="display: none">
   <img class= "tree1" src="img/tree1.jpeg">
   <img class= "tree2" src="img/tree2.jpeg">
   <img class= "tree3" src="img/roots.jpeg">
</div>
<div>
   <button onclick="show_hide()">Click to Reveal</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var a = 1;
function show_hide()
{
    if(a==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("image").style.display="inline";
        return a=0;
    }

    else
    {
        document.getElementById("image").style.display="none";
        return a=1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's  it just assign the value of 0 to the var before doing anything and call the function. It was that easy. I hope I solved your query you can run this code snippet to check if it works!
Thanks!

```js
var a = 0;
show_hide()
function show_hide()
{
    if(a==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("image").style.display="inline";
        return a=0;
    }

    else
    {
        document.getElementById("image").style.display="none";
        return a=1;
    }

}
```

```html
    <div id="image">
            <img class= "tree1" src="img/tree1.jpeg">
            <img class= "tree2" src="img/tree2.jpeg">
            <img class= "tree3" src="img/roots.jpeg">
        </div>
      <div>
        <button onclick="show_hide()">Click to Reveal</button>
      </div>

      <script src="showhideelement.js"></script>
```